# Form Validation Not Working Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the form validation... I also want to display error messages wether the for was submitted successfully or not.

Currently, I'm using a `DetailView`, where a person can fill in a `BookingForm()`

**forms.py**
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):
    Name = forms.CharField()
    Postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=8,label='Postcode')
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    Phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15,validators=[phone_regex],label='Phone')
    Date = forms.CharField(max_length=30,label='Date')
    Time = forms.CharField(max_length=10,label='Time')
```

In my **views.py** I defined `def post` to allow post requests. However, I always get the ELSE loop returned

```
def post(self,request,**kwargs):
    # put your own credentials here

    form = BookingForm(self.request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_phone = form.cleaned_data['Phone']
        postcode = form.cleaned_data['Postcode']
        date = form.cleaned_data['Date']
        account_sid = "***"
        auth_token = "***"
        found = Model.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        client.messages.create(
            to=Model.phone_number,
            from_="+442033225719",
            body="You have a new booking." +
                 "Call phone number:{}. Address: {}. Date:{}"
                     .format(user_phone,postcode,date))
        messages.success(request, 'Your booking was reserved.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error occurred.')
    return redirect('users:detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

And my **model_detail.html** which handles the form.

**FURTHER EDIT:**

I created the following HTML template which I include in the main template using `{% include 'booking_form.html' %}`:

```
<!-- Book Now -->
            <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="boxed-widget">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o "></i> Book Now</h3>
                <div class="row with-forms margin-top-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        {{ form.name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Full Name:</label>
                        {{ form.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                          {{ form.postcode.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.postcode.id_for_label }}">Postcode:</label>
                        {{ form.postcode }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row with-forms  margin-top-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        {{ form.name.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Full Name:</label>
                        {{ form.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row with-forms  margin-top-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        {{ form.date.errors }}
                        <input name="Date" type="text" id="booking-date" data-lang="en" data-large-mode="true" data-min-year="2017" data-max-year="2020">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                        {{ form.time.errors }}
                        <input name="Time" type="text" id="booking-time" value="9:00 am">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- progress button animation handled via custom.js -->
                <button type="submit" class="progress-button button fullwidth margin-top-5"><span>Book Now</span></button>
            </div>
            </form>
<!-- Book Now / End -->
```

My BookingForm in **forms.py** has remained unchanged. However, now, I see no fields to input. I'm assuming this is because the form is not passed into the template.

Full content of my **views.py** of the DetailView:

```
class TeacherView(generic.DetailView,FormMixin):
    model = Teacher
    form_class = BookingForm

  def post(self,request,**kwargs):

      form = BookingForm(self.request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        user_phone = form.cleaned_data['Phone']
        account_sid = "***"
        auth_token = "***"
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        client.messages.create(
            to=teacher.phone_number,
            from_="+442033225719",
            body=""
        messages.success(request, 'Success Message')
        return redirect('users:index')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error occured.')
        return redirect("users:index")



 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(TeacherView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add extra context from another model
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always redirecting, whether the form is valid or not, so obviously you can't have the form errors displayed. If you want the form errors to be shown in your template, you need to render the template and return it as response when the validation fail - example with a plain function-based view (if you insist on using generic class-based views then [use a `FormMixin` with your `DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview)):

```
def myview(request, ...):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST):
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_the_form(...)
            messages.success(request, "success message here")
            return redirect(where you want to redirect)
    else:
       # GET, display an empty form
       form = MyForm()
   return render(request, "mytemplate.html", context={"form":form})
```

Also in your template you need to use the form itself instead of hardcoding it, [as explained here in the FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

wrt/ the `messages` framework's messages not displaying either, this is certainly a configuration issue, so re-read the `messages` doc and check your settings etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read this just now. Regarding the hardcoding, I did it for styling purposes, as I can display it in a nicer format.

Comment: @Roma you don't have to completely bypass the form's feature in your template to get full control on the rendering, cf the second link in my answer.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I tried to replicate this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/ , but I can't manage to get it to work still. I added the edit above. What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: @Roma: as the doc explains, it quickly becomes a mess. That's why I stick to function-based views unless I have a very very compelling reason to use CBVs (which only happened once so far and I've been using Django since the 0.9x days). If you re-read my answer, you'll see that the canonical 'display some content and handle a form' function-based view is dead simple and perfectly clear - the only important point being to redirect __only__ if the form validates.

Comment: I see, so in the Else loop, I will add object = Model.objects.get(pk=pk), and add it to the context in the render function. I'm also curious how I can redirect to the same page (since it's a detailed view, in my case it's a teacher profile). I tried render(request, "users/teacher_detail.html", pk=self.kwargs['pk']) to identify the correct teacher...

Comment: I'm basically trying to show a booking form on each teacher profile (which was my previous DetailView), now it seems I need to code it myself, probably by including <pk> as a parameter? E.g. def MyView(request, pk):